# running integration tests in teamcity using spring-boot and restassured

Tags: maven, teamcity, spring-boot, rest-assured

I am writing my integration tests using springboot and rest-assured and using SpringApplicationConfiguration to load the configuration.

This is what the test class annotation look like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = RestAPIApplication.class)
@IntegrationTest("server.port:8083") // this is the port set by my application
```

Now comes my real question. When I run the test class in teamcity using maven, don't I have to configure something to run the springboot server before running the integration tests?

I am new to springboot so maybe this question is very novice but please point me to the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using embedded tomcat, no extra setup is needed-- simply run the maven tests.

Comment: when you say embedded tomcat are you referring to the one that is present in spring-boot?

Comment: correct. if you're packaging as a jar (see the pom <packaging>), that's what you're doing

Comment: Thanks @gyoder I solved the problem by using failsafe plugin in the pom.